# Is it possible to count the records stored in hyperledger fabric blockchain,i dont want to fetch data from statedb

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, ibm-blockchain

i want to fetch data from blockchain ledger instead of statedb like couch and leveldb.i want to write chaincode method that count the total record from blockchain ledger.

Answer (score 1):

Chaincode API doesn't provide such functionality if I'm not mistaken, you can only get state by key or perform a rich query if you use couchdb for example.